# Jquery toggle does not hide/show specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce

I am trying to hide/show a variations form for each product. Basically if the user clicks on the quick shop button, the variation form related to that product will open. If they select it again, it will hide it for that product.

The problem is that I don't know how to hide or show it specifically for the product which the quick shop button belongs to. The html is derived from woocommerce so I will be unable to go into the html and provide separate ids to differentiate.

Here is some screenshots on what happens at the moment:

Here are three products, each with their own quick shop button (ignore and apologies for the mute speaker on the icon)

[image]

I select the middle product's quick shop button but as you can see it opens up the variation form for the first product:

[image]

Then when I click on the middle quick shop button again to hide the variation form, instead it opens all variation forms:

[image]

So yeah, that's my issue. Help please :)

Jquery:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    
   jQuery( '.quick_shop' ).click(function() {     
   jQuery('.variations_form').toggle('slide', { direction: 'down' }, 300);
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="quick_shop_container">
  <button class="quick_shop">
    <span class="quick_shop_text">Quick Shop &nbsp;</span>
      <span class="quick_shop_price"> 
 | From £24.99   </span>
  </button> 
</div>

<form class=“variations_form”>
//REST OF FORM UNDERNEATH
```

CSS:

```
.variations_form{
    display:none;
}
```

HTML code structure (manipulated code best I can to remove unneeded code):

```
`<ul class="products columns-3">
   <li class="pif-has-gallery  column-1_3 product type-product">
      <div class="post_item_wrap">
         <div class="post_featured">
            <div class="post_thumb">
               <a class="hover_icon hover_icon_link" href="">
                  <div class="container-image-and-badge  ">
                     <img>
                        <div class="yith-wcbm-badge__wrap">
                           <img>            
                        </div>
                        <!--yith-wcbm-badge__wrap-->
                     </div>
                     <!--yith-wcbm-badge-->
                  </div>
                  <!--container-image-and-badge-->
<img>               
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="post_content">
            <a class="" href="xxx?product=espresso-coffee-taster-pack">
            </a>
            <div class="quick_shop_container">
               <button class="quick_shop">
               <span class="quick_shop_text">Quick Shop &nbsp;</span>
               <span class="quick_shop_price"> 
               | From £24.99      </span>
               </button> 
            </div>
           <form class="variations_form">
            ...
            </form>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class="pif-has-gallery  column-1_3 product type-product">
      <div class="post_item_wrap">
         <div class="post_featured">
            <div class="post_thumb">
               <a class="hover_icon hover_icon_link" href="xxx?product=speciality-coffee-taster-pack">
                  <div class="container-image-and-badge  ">
                     <img>
                        <div class="yith-wcbm-badge__wrap">
                           <img>            
                        </div>
                        <!--yith-wcbm-badge__wrap-->
                     </div>
                     <!--yith-wcbm-badge-->
                  </div>
                  <!--container-image-and-badge--><img>             
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="post_content">
            <a class="" href="xxx?product=speciality-coffee-taster-pack">
            </a>
            <div class="quick_shop_container">
               <button class="quick_shop">
               <span class="quick_shop_text">Quick Shop &nbsp;</span>
               <span class="quick_shop_price"> 
               | From £31.99      </span>
               </button> 
            </div>
           <form class="variations_form">
            ...
            </form>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class="pif-has-gallery  column-1_3 product type-product">
      <div class="post_item_wrap">
         <div class="post_featured">
            <div class="post_thumb">
               <a class="hover_icon hover_icon_link" href="xxx?product=12-month-coffee-subscription">
               <img>                </a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="post_content">
            <a class="" href="xxx?product=12-month-coffee-subscription">
            </a>
            <div class="quick_shop_container">
               <button class="quick_shop">
               <span class="quick_shop_text">Quick Shop &nbsp;</span>
               <span class="quick_shop_price"> 
               | £125.99      </span>
               </button> 
            </div>
            <form class="variations_form">
            ...
            </form>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
  
</ul>`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your jQuery selector selects all `.variation_form` elements
You can select the closest `.quick_shop_container`, and the next `.variations_form` element:

```
jQuery(this).closest('.quick_shop_container').next('.variations_form').toggle('slide', { direction: 'down' }, 300);
```

Comment: Ok interesting, it looks like it's opening the correct form based on the quick shop button, just one additional question. It's not hiding the form when I click the quick shop button again, would you know why that is?

Comment: Hmmz, No, clicking the button again would trigger the toggle so it should hide. I would check if the elements style changes when you click the button the second time in the element inspector (the style attribute will change).

Comment: Ah cool, I will check that out. Thank you Gert for your help :)

Comment: It was the toggle slide animation, when I remove the slide down and time duration, it works. The console was throwing looping errors so will check that out but worked beautifully in terms of hide and showing the correct form :) Thank you

Comment: Maybe slideToggle() does the trick instead of toggle? just an idea :-)

Comment: Yep, I did that straight after my comment and worked beautifully. Thanks again man for the above :)